# Getting a 1064 Error in MySQL but query still completes? Not sure why!

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert a lot of fields into a MySQL database, some are failing, so I am adding some code into my PHP script to try and track down what is occurring.

The replace seems to work as I can see the fields being populated in mysql, but I get this error:

> 1064:You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

```
//insert query
if (strlen($link_name)>0)
{
$query = mysql_query("REPLACE into jos_mt_links
(link_id, link_name, alias, link_desc, user_id, link_approved, metadesc, link_created, link_modified, website, price)
VALUES ('$link_id','$link_name','$link_name','$description','63','1','$metadesc','$link_created','$link_modified','$website','$cost')");
echo $link_name . "has been inserted <br />";
print "SQL-Query: ".$query."<br>";

    if(mysql_query($query,$db))
   {
    echo "<center><font face='$fonts' size=2 color='$green'>";
    echo " OK !</font><br><br>\n";
   }
  else
   {
    echo "<center><font face='$fonts' size=3 color='$red'>";
    echo "Error<br><br>";
       echo mysql_errno() . ":" . mysql_error() . "</font><br>\n";
   }
```

Comment: Are all of the string values (e.g. $link_id, $link_name, etc) correctly escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your SQL. You're assigning `$query` to the result of your `mysql_query()` call:

```
$query = mysql_query("REPLACE into jos_mt_links
    (link_id, link_name, alias, link_desc, user_id, link_approved, metadesc,
    link_created, link_modified, website, price)
    VALUES
    ('$link_id','$link_name','$link_name','$description','63','1','$metadesc','$link_created','$link_modified','$website','$cost')");
```

`mysql_query()` returns `true` or `false` as a result of the `REPLACE` query, but the more important thing is that you're assigning the result, not the SQL query that you're executing.

Furthermore, in here:

```
if(mysql_query($query,$db))
```

You're calling `mysql_query()` *again* on the same `$query` variable which now holds a value of `true` (since you said your query is working and your database is being updated normally). PHP interprets boolean `true` as string `'1'` and you're telling MySQL to run a query called `1`, which gives that error.

You probably meant to assign `$query` like this instead so your if condition works properly:

```
$query = "REPLACE into jos_mt_links
    (link_id, link_name, alias, link_desc, user_id, link_approved, metadesc,
    link_created, link_modified, website, price)
    VALUES
    ('$link_id','$link_name','$link_name','$description','63','1','$metadesc','$link_created','$link_modified','$website','$cost')";
```

And calling your `echo` within the if statement too.

Another thing: as what Mark Baker has noted, please be sure your variables have been escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before sticking them directly in your SQL like that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Could you clarify how I check I am using a mysql_real_escape_string()? From checking it appears the records that fail have an apostrophe in the description. ie a record with this in the description just failed

we'd

Comment: The safest thing to do is assume the variables coming in are all unescaped, and running that function on them just before running the query.

Comment: I've done some searching and all the examples, ie here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php talk about needing it for POST and GET, neither of which I am doing, so is it still necessary?

Comment: As long as the data you're inserting comes from an untrusted source, i.e. something other than your own code's generated data, then yes it is still necessary.